# Возможно ли в Unix отправить сообщение через сокет по частям, не разделяя буфер, в котором оно находится

Tags: c, unix

Возможно ли с помощью `write()` или `send()` отправить буфер (массив байт), размер которого привосходит допустимый для отправки одним сообщением, по частям, но не разделяя сам буфер на подмассивы. Иными словами, есть ли у `write()` механизмы, благодаря которым он запоминает на каком месте он остановился (как у `read()` с чтением из файла)?

Comment: @AlexF, т.е сообщение разделится без моего вмешательства ?

Comment: `send()` возвращает число отправленных байт (или -1 при ошибке), и если это число меньше размера буфера, то можно вызвать `send()` ещё раз начиная с первого неотправленного байта. Правда, это вроде бы работает только в неблокирующем режиме, а в обычном `send()` зависнет до тех пор, пока не отправит весь буфер целиком (по крайней мере в моей личной практике всегда было только так)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ssize_t write(int fd, const void *buf, size_t count);`

Возвращает количество байт, которые отправил или код ошибки.

Если не ошибка, сами смещайте указатель `buf` на отправленное ранее количество байт, и  уменьшайте `count` на то же значение.

Вызывать повторно пока уменьшенный `count` не сократится до нуля или не получим ошибку.

У `send` поведение похоже, но дополнительно настраивается флагами.